# Using mysqli_connect() for Wordpress connection to Cloud SQL on Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to run Wordpress on Google App Engine standard environment.  I have configured a Cloud SQL for MySQL Second Generation instance and can access it using Cloud SQL Proxy with this command:

```
cloud_sql_proxy  -instances=my_project_id:us-central1:my_project=tcp:3306
```

The `wp-config.php` file:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['GAE_ENV'])) {
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/my_project_id:us-central1:my_project'); 
} else {
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'); 
}
```

Finally, I connect to the database using this:

```
$dbConn = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die (mysqli_error($dbConn));
mysqli_select_db($dbConn, DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_error($dbConn));
```

This setup works perfectly from the local development environment, which is Cloud Shell.  The website runs and I am able to query the database and insert records etc.  My problem arises when I deploy to `my_project_id.appspot.com` using `google app deploy`.  The website runs, but when I try to query the database I receive this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /srv/wp-content/themes/mytheme/system/db.php on line 14
```

Line 14 is `$dbConn = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)`
 so I am guessing that mysqli must not like the format of the specified `DB_HOST` which is `:/cloudsql/my_project_id:us-central1:my_project`.

In this [Community Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-sql) there is sample code which uses a unix socket and PDO to connect to the database.  I don't know if I should be adding these lines to the `app.yaml` file and someone using this different connection string.

```
env_variables:
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/my_project_id:us-central1:my_project;dbname=my_dbname
  MYSQL_USER: username
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

My apologies for the lengthy question, but I wanted to provide as much information as possible.  Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be passing in the information incorrectly into `mysqli_connect`. If you take a look a the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) for it, it actually takes in 6 parameters: `host`, `username`, `passwd`, `dbname`, `port`, `socket`.

Under host, you can read the following:

> Passing the NULL value or the string "localhost" to this parameter, the local host is assumed. When possible, pipes will be used instead of the TCP/IP protocol.

Under socket, it clarifies it should be the socket path:

> Specifies the socket or named pipe that should be used.

So you need to call mysqli_connect like this:

```
mysqli_connect (null, "user", "password", "database", 3306, "/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>")
```

Comment: Thanks Kurtis for this suggestion.  I think you are onto something, but I am not out of the woods just yet.   I tried your suggestion to reference all 6 of the optional parameters of mysqli_connect, but I am still not able to connect.  I created a new question that better explains the current status of my connection problem.  The new question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683958/connect-to-cloud-sql-in-google-app-engine-using-mysqli-connect

Answer (score 1):

From Cloud Shell, your environment is all setup properly in order to directly connect to Cloud SQL. From AppEngine there's a few other steps necessary in order to connect.

Check out this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine

It should get you up and running.

Comment: Do I need to add a Service Account in this format?  service-[YOUR_PROJECT_NUMBER]@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: For the proxy, yeah. The name format doesn't matter for the account, just the roles/permissions you grant it.

Comment: So I had done that already, added a Service Account with the appropriate roles/permissions.  In fact, I did it again and added another Service Account with the same roles/permissions.  What I don't understand is how the Service Account is associated with the GAE project?  I don't see how they are tied together.

Comment: Oooh, with a H/T to a coworker of mine who I think spotted the issue. The HOST should always be localhost (null in the mysql_connect() call). You need to then pass the socket parameter to that call. He's typing up an answer as we speak.

Comment: Thanks @GabeWeiss.  I tried the suggestion that Kurtisvg gave me, but it did not work so I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683958/connect-to-cloud-sql-in-google-app-engine-using-mysqli-connect

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Kurtisvg is absolutely correct in terms of this being the proper format for connecting to Cloud SQL using `mysqli_connect`:

```php
mysqli_connect (null, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 3306, "/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>")
```

The original question, however, also mentioned that I was trying to get the connection working for a Wordpress installation.  These are the two areas with additional information relevant to this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard) on how to run Wordpress on Google App Engine standard.

**1.  Specifying correct mysqli_connect() parameters**
Testing the app in the local development environment only required `mysqli_connect` to use these four parameters: `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_NAME`.  Once the app is deployed to Google App Engine, the `mysqli_connect` has to use all six parameters: `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_NAME`, `DB_PORT`, `DB_SOCK`.  This is the code in db.php that provides the correct parameters, depending on the environment:

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['GAE_ENV'])) {
    $dbConn = mysqli_connect (null, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT, DB_SOCK); 
} else {  // local environment
    $dbConn = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    }
```

**2. Specify correct Wordpress configuration in wp-config.php**
What I was finding was that in order `Wordpress` to function correctly, it was necessary to not only define and use the socket `DB_SOCK` in `mysqli_connect()`, but I also had to define a `DB_HOST` for purposes of the `Wordpress` installation. This was the configuration that worked in my wp-config.php file:

```php
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database');
define('DB_PORT', 3306);    

// Check for Google App Engine Environment
if (isset($_SERVER['GAE_ENV'])) {
    $onGae = true;
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>'); 
    define('DB_SOCK', '/cloudsql/<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>');
} else {
    $onGae = false;
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'); 
}
```

In the above code, the variable for `DB_HOST` requires a full-colon `:` at the beginning of the socket.  This `DB_HOST` variable is not used as one of the connection parameters of `mysqli_connect` when in the GAE environment.  This variable does seem to be used elsewhere in Wordpress (such as setup-config.php), which is why it needs to be defined.  The variable for `DB_SOCK` does not require the full-colon `:` in order to work in the GAE environment.  This socket needs to be the last (6th) parameter of `mysqli_connect`, with the first parameter specified as `null`, which forces the connection to use the socket.

It took a while to get this sorted, but eventually got it working using these settings above.  I wonder if anyone else had such a complicated experience as I did getting Wordpress on Google App Engine standard environment to connect to a Cloud SQL for MySQL Second Generation instance.  I hope these comments help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using wpdb class.  Wpdb is a WordPress database access abstraction class.  Check out this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)