# Connect to Cloud SQL in Google App Engine using mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to configure my Wordpress site in the Google App Engine standard environment.  I have configured a Cloud SQL for MySQL Second Generation instance and can access it using Cloud SQL Proxy.

The problem I have is connected to the Cloud SQL instance after the app has been deployed to the Google App Engine (GAE) environment.  Here are two different connection strings; one for the GAE environment and another for the local environment.

```php
if (isset($_SERVER['GAE_ENV'])) {
    $dbConn = mysqli_connect (null, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, 3306, DB_SOCK); 
} else {  // local environment
    $dbConn = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
}
```

**Local environment**
The connection string for the local environment works perfectly when I use these 4 parameters:  `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_NAME`.  When I try to use the same connection string with four parameters in the GAE environment, it throws an error:

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`

**GAE Environment**
In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650687/using-mysqli-connect-for-wordpress-connection-to-cloud-sql-on-google-app-engin), I was told to call `mysqli_connect` using all 6 of the optional parameters, with `null` for parameter 1 and `3306` for parameter 5, being the port.  When I try to make the connection using the GAE connection string with these 6 parameters: `null`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_NAME`, `3306`, `DB_SOCK`, I get a slightly different error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: No such file or directory
```

Here is the code from `wp-config.php` which sets the connection string variables depending on the environment:

```
if ($onGae) {
    /** GAE Environment */
    define('DB_NAME', 'database');
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/project_id:region:instance_id');
    define('DB_USER', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
} else {
    /** Local environment */
    define('DB_NAME', 'database');
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_USER', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
}
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get `mysqli_connect` to connect to CloudSQL from GAE.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: Just as something to try...change the DB_HOST to 'localhost' in the GAE environment as well and confirm that you get the same error message (eliminating some easy to knock out things).

Comment: Thanks Gabe.  I tried your suggestion to change the DB_HOST to `localhost`, but when I did that I get an 'Error establishing a database connection'.  This makes sense because without specifying the ':/cloudsql/project_id:region:instance_id' it won't know which database to connect to.  I assume you were telling me to change the DB_HOST entry in the wp-config.php file and not in the mysqli_connect call, right?

Comment: No that's good. I was wanting to confirm that the "file missing" wasn't the socket for some reason. That error usually means the database isn't available (not Cloud SQL now, we're talking the MySQL db under it). I'm on the move today, I'll see if I can poke someone to take a look too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the colon in the path of your socket is preventing it from recognizing it is an absolute path. Try `define('DB_HOST', '/cloudsql/<project_id:region:instance_id>');` instead.

A couple of other tips: You can use the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) to create a local unix socket at `/cloudsql/<CONNECTION_NAME>`, which means you can test the same code deployed and locally.

Also as general programming advice, I would try to avoid using `DB_HOST` for different types of values (because they really aren't the same). This will help you from inadvertently using `$DB_HOST` somewhere else and expecting an IP address. Try something like this instead:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
if ($onGae) {
    /** GAE Environment */
    define('DB_HOST', null);
    define('DB_SOCKET', '/cloudsql/project_id:region:instance_id');
} else {
    /** Local environment */
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_SOCKET', null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kurtisvg, your answer was spot on.  I had to configure a few additional things that were particular to Wordpress.  Those additional steps are shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650687/using-mysqli-connect-for-wordpress-connection-to-cloud-sql-on-google-app-engin/57743429#57743429